# Operator Graph generation

Tags: apache-spark

I just want to know what will happen when the textFile is changed in between transformation and action.
For example, I create a RDD from a textFile which is of 1 MB and do a flatMap transformation but before 
calling the action .collect, I replace the file in the local file system with 100 MB textFile with the same name.

Since Operator Graph is generated after the action call, shouldn't DAG be computed from the large file?

```
// RDD created from 1 MB File size
val a = sc.textFile("c:/SampleData.txt").flatMap(x => x.split(" "))

// Replace the textfile SampleData.txt(1 MB size) with SampleData (100 MB   size)
a.collect
```

But when I tried doing it,  I got this exception

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Cannot seek after EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically Spark doesn't even validate existence of the RDD input (there are exceptions) until data is actually needed. Spark will compute splits when action is called, using new file.

Answer (score 0):

Spark will use the file which ever is available while executing the action. Spark uses a lazy mechanism. While we are writing transformations on RDDs, all Spark does is just create a DAG for the operation. The entire execution kicks in as soon as you call some action involving the RDDs. Hence, in this case, it will use the latest file that is available.

Hope this helps!